# How can I identify what java.lang.NumberFormatException e's default value is and use it in an if statement

Tags: java, eclipse

trying to get outputs depending on what java.lang.NumberFormatException e is after the try{}.

```
String o = "";
try {
    //Does something with o
}catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
    if(e != null) {//<-

    console.log("Incorrect input at: " + o);

    }else if(e == null){//<-

    System.out.println("Working fine!");

    }
}
```

I'm looking to find what to use instead of null in the catch if statement

Comment: `e` can never be `null`. If there's no exception, then the `try` block is simply executed without going to the `catch` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
String o = "";
try{
       //Does something with o
       System.out.println("Working fine!");

   }
   catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e) 

   {
    
       console.log("Incorrect input at: " + o);
    
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is not how Java's exceptions work.

NumberFormatException occurs only when your try statement throws a relevant exception.

Over here in your case.  e != null or e==null these checks are unnecessary due to the fact that once an exception is thrown those are bound to be not null.

Instead what you should be doing is as follows:

```
String o = "";
try {
// all the sanity checks will be here.
if (o==null) {
  console.log("o is null");
}

// your processing of valid number.

}catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
//invalid input is found
console.log("Incorrect input of o: " + e);
}
```

Hope this helps, Thanks.